# Calculating mean of rows defined by row names in a file

Tags: r, mean

I have two files/datasets: 1) 2 columns and 80,000 rows. First column includes only row names (gene list), 2nd column their expression values 2) is a gene cluster files, I have over 27,000 cluster each identified by multiple genes (from 200 to 1). I want to calculate mean expression value for each gene cluster.

How can I do it using R?

```
#dataset 1
gene1      2.4
gene2      5.2
gene3      0.1
...
gene80000  2.1

#dataset 2 
cluster 1     gene1 gene2 gene80 gene34500
cluster 2     gene3 gene4
cluster 3     gene16000 gene2200
....
cluster 27992 gene5 gene10 gene135
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of dataset 2? Is it a data frame with a single list column for the genes? A character column for the genes? Multiple character columns with blanks or missing values (which?) for the numbers of columns? Posting `dput(head(dataset2))` or maybe `dput(droplevels(head(dataset2)))` will clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

```r
df2$clust_mean = sapply(df2$genes, 
                          function(x) mean(df1[match(strsplit(as.character(x), split="\\s")[[1]], df1$gene),
                                               "value"], na.rm=T))
df2
```

Output is:

```
    cluster                   genes clust_mean
1 cluster 1       gene1 gene2 gene3   2.566667
2 cluster 2                   gene1   2.400000
3 cluster 3 gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4   1.975000
```

```
#sample data - I have slightly modified the values in your sample data to make the illustration simple
> dput(df1)
structure(list(gene = structure(1:4, .Label = c("gene1", "gene2", 
"gene3", "gene4"), class = "factor"), value = c(2.4, 5.2, 0.1, 
0.2)), .Names = c("gene", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
> dput(df2)
structure(list(cluster = structure(1:3, .Label = c("cluster 1", 
"cluster 2", "cluster 3"), class = "factor"), genes = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("gene1", "gene1 gene2 gene3", "gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("cluster", "genes"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: This is looking great. Can you help me to modify the command based on my data? Here is what I have so far:                                                              df1 <- read.table("counts3096S1.txt",header=TRUE)
dim(df1)
[1] 80029     2
names(df1)
[1] "gene"  "value"

Comment: And then x <- scan("clusters3096.txt", what="", sep="\n")

Comment: y <- strsplit(x, "[[:space:]]+")

Comment: names(y) <- sapply(y, `[[`, 1)

Comment: y <- lapply(y, `[`, -1)

Comment: As you see my df2 is actually y and it does not have the headers. Can you still help me?

Comment: Considering `df1` as a dataframe and `y` as a list (as explained in your comment) I would suggest you to try `clust_mean = lapply(y, function(x) mean(df1[match(x, df1$gene), "value"], na.rm=T))`